# How to order a list of integers from greatest to least?

Tags: c

I have an assignment where I must use a structure to put in student information. I must then order the credit hours from greatest to least. I am focused on the integer ordering loop, I just can't figure out why my program is outputting incorrectly.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student {
    char name[21];
    int credits;
} s[99];

int main()
{
    int students;
    int tempCred = 0;
    char tempName[21];

    printf("How many students?: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &students);

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent Name?: ");
        scanf_s("%s", &s[i].name, 21);

        printf("\nCredits Taken?: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &s[i].credits);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < students; j++) {
            if (s[j].credits > tempCred) {
                tempCred = s[j].credits;
                s[i].credits = s[j].credits;
                s[j].credits = tempCred;
            }
        }

        printf("\n%d", s[i].credits);
    }
}
```

For example, if I were to enter 2,6, and 8 when asked for credit hours, the program would output '8,6,8'. I am not unfamiliar with sorting, but for some reason something isn't making sense when I look at this code. Could anyone help me order the integers from greatest to least? Thanks!

NOTE: I am aware there are better ways to do this, but my professor is making us use strictly C, no C++ at all. I just need help ordering the integers.

Comment: Use the `qsort()` function instead of writing your own sorting code.

Comment: For starters you are printing the result *during* the sort instead of *after* it.

Comment: So basically you are having some students have their credit hours stolen?

Comment: Try `for (int j = i+1; j < students; j++) {   if (s[i].credits < s[j].credits)`

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code to trace the logic. If you don't know how to use one, now is the perfect time to learn. There is no better tool available for understanding exactly what your code is doing (and not doing).

Answer (score 0):

There are various techniques used for sorting. For instance the bubble sort, quick sort, insertion sort, etc. The simplest one is the bubble sort - but it's not the most efficient one.

In your program you have an array of `struct`s. You've done the inserting part of the structs into the array and that's fine. The problem lies in the second part - the sorting. You have a `for` loop that starts at the very first element (i.e. 0) and goes all the way up to the last element (i.e. students-1). And nested inside this loop is another `for` loop - that also has the same range???

No, that's wrong. Instead replace the first and second `for` loops with this:

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < students-1 ; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i+1 ; j < students ; j++) 
        {
             ...
        }
    }
```

Here, the outer `for` loop begins with element 0 and goes up to the **element before the last**. The inner `for` loop starts  with the next element to what the outer `for` loop stores (i.e. j = i + 1). So if i = 0, j = 1. And this loop goes all the way up to the last element of the array of structs.

Now, inside the inner `for` loop specify the condition. In your case you want them sorted in descending order (highest to lowest) of the credits.

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < students-1 ; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i+1 ; j < students ; j++) 
        {
            if(s[j].credits > s[i].credits)         // then swap the credits
            {
                tempCred = s[j].credits ;
                s[j].credits = s[i].credits ;
                s[i].credits = tempCred ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that j is one greater that i. So if i = 0, j = 1, then the `if` statement reads

> If the credits held in the struct in element 1 of the array is greater than the credits stored in the struct in element 0 of the array, then...

If the condition is met, the credits in these 2 structs are swapped.

This an implementation of the "bubble sort". See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) for more techniques and explanations.

Finally, you can display the credits:

```
    for(int index = 0 ; index < students ; index++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", s[index].credits) ;
    }
```

Like a lot of people in the comments have said, use debugger. It'll help you trace the logic of your programs.

Comment: see this actually answers my question. Thanks for the help, that's all I needed. Sorry I'm not a professional everyone. I thought that was understood by me asking a question.

Comment: You're welcome @Harl23. Do consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Like [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said use the `qsort()` [function](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html) from glibc.
Not only is easier than writting your own method but it is *much* faster at [O(N log N)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/?ref=leftbar-rightbar) on average.

Comment: The function `qsort` is part of the C standard library. On some platforms, it is implemented in `glibc`, but not all platforms use that library.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, because it does not address the issue in the poster's code. This is a good suggestion for an alternative, but before making that suggestion you should answer the asked question.